# No such file or directory C++

Tags: android, c++, directory

I downloaded a project test from github and when i want to run the app i get this error in the image link [Error Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3cZI.jpg)

*app gradle:*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
repositories {
    libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {
        prebuilt {
            headers.srcDir "../../../package/include"
            binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                sharedLibraryFile = file("../../../package/Android/libs/armeabi-v7a/libEasyAR.so")
            }
        }
    }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion = 25
    buildToolsVersion = "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig.with {
        applicationId = "com.jerome.unitydemo"
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 15
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 22
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }



    sources {
        main {

            jni {
                dependencies {
                    library "prebuilt"
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
android.buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.pro"))
    }
}
android.ndk {
    moduleName = "HelloARVideoNative"
    cppFlags.add("-I${file("../../../package/include")}".toString())
    cppFlags.add("-DANDROID")
    cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
    cppFlags.add("-frtti")
    stl = "gnustl_static"
    ldLibs.add("log")
    ldLibs.add("GLESv2")
}

android.productFlavors {
    create("arm") {
        ndk.with {
            abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
        }
    }

}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
}
```

*Android.mk*

```
LOCAL_PATH_TOP := $(call my-dir)
EASYAR_PACKAGE_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH_TOP)/../../../../../../package

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PATH := $(EASYAR_PACKAGE_PATH)/Android/libs/armeabi-v7a
LOCAL_MODULE:=libEasyAR
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:=libEasyAR.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH_TOP)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(EASYAR_PACKAGE_PATH)/include
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -DANDROID
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -lGLESv2
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libEasyAR
LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cc
LOCAL_MODULE := libHelloARNative
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ar.cc helloarvideo.cc renderer.cc
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

*Application.mk*

```
APP_OPTIM := release
APP_PLATFORM := android-17
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_MODULES := HelloARNative
NDK_TOOLCHAIN := arm-linux-androideabi-4.9
```

**And this all of the file in my jni** [Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suxGj.jpg)

I was struggling with this error without any result Please Help.

*ar.hpp*

```
#ifndef __EASYAR_SAMPLE_UTILITY_AR_H__
#define __EASYAR_SAMPLE_UTILITY_AR_H__

#include "easyar/camera.hpp"
#include "easyar/imagetracker.hpp"
#include "easyar/augmenter.hpp"
#include "easyar/imagetarget.hpp"
#include "easyar/frame.hpp"
#include "easyar/player.hpp"
#include "easyar/utility.hpp"
#include <string>

namespace EasyAR{
namespace samples{

class AR
{
public:
AR();
virtual ~AR();
virtual bool initCamera();
virtual void loadFromImage(const std::string& path);
virtual void loadFromJsonFile(const std::string& path, const std::string&        targetname);
virtual void loadAllFromJsonFile(const std::string& path);
virtual bool start();
virtual bool stop();
virtual bool clear();

virtual void initGL();
virtual void resizeGL(int width, int height);
virtual void render();
void setPortrait(bool portrait);
protected:
CameraDevice camera_;
ImageTracker tracker_;
Augmenter augmenter_;
bool portrait_;
Vec4I viewport_;
};

class ARVideo {
public:
ARVideo();
~ARVideo();

void openVideoFile(const std::string& path, int texid);
void openTransparentVideoFile(const std::string& path, int texid);
void openStreamingVideo(const std::string& url, int texid);

void setVideoStatus(VideoPlayer::Status status);
void onFound();
void onLost();
void seek(int pos);
int currentPosition();
int duration();
bool pause();
bool play();
void update();

class CallBack : public VideoPlayerCallBack
{
public:
    CallBack(ARVideo* video);
    void operator() (VideoPlayer::Status status);
private:
    ARVideo* video_;
};

private:
VideoPlayer player_;
bool prepared_;
bool found_;
CallBack* callback_;
std::string path_;
};

}
}
#endif
```

*ar.cc*

```
#include "ar.hpp"
#include <algorithm>
#ifdef ANDROID
#include <android/log.h>
#define LOGI(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "EasyAR", __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define LOGI(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#endif

namespace EasyAR{
namespace samples{

class HelloCallBack :
public TargetLoadCallBack
{
public:
virtual ~HelloCallBack() {
};
virtual void operator() (const Target target, const bool status)
{
LOGI("load target: %s (%d) %s\n", target.name(), target.id(), status ? "success" : "fail");
delete this;
}
};

AR::AR()
{
portrait_ = false;
}

AR::~AR()
{
clear();
}

bool AR::initCamera()
{
bool status = true;
status &= camera_.open();
camera_.setSize(Vec2I(1280, 720));
status &= tracker_.attachCamera(camera_);
status &= augmenter_.attachCamera(camera_);
return status;
}


void AR::loadFromImage(const std::string& path)
{
ImageTarget target;
std::string jstr = "{\n"
"  \"images\" :\n"
"  [\n"
"    {\n"
"      \"image\" : \"" + path + "\",\n"
"      \"name\" : \"" + path.substr(0, path.find_first_of(".")) + "\"\n"
"    }\n"
"  ]\n"
"}";
target.load(jstr.c_str(), EasyAR::kStorageAssets | EasyAR::kStorageJson);
tracker_.loadTarget(target, new HelloCallBack());
}

void AR::loadFromJsonFile(const std::string& path, const std::string& targetname)
{
ImageTarget target;
target.load(path.c_str(), EasyAR::kStorageAssets, targetname.c_str());
tracker_.loadTarget(target, new HelloCallBack());
}

void AR::loadAllFromJsonFile(const std::string& path)
{
TargetList targets = ImageTarget::loadAll(path.c_str(), EasyAR::kStorageAssets);
for (int i = 0; i < targets.size(); ++i) {
tracker_.loadTarget(targets[i], new HelloCallBack());
}
}

bool AR::start()
{
bool status = true;
status &= camera_.start();
camera_.setFocusMode(CameraDevice::kFocusModeContinousauto);
status &= tracker_.start();
return status;
}



bool AR::stop()
{
bool status = true;
status &= tracker_.stop();
status &= camera_.stop();
return status;
}

bool AR::clear()
{
bool status = true;
status &= stop();
status &= camera_.close();
camera_.clear();
tracker_.clear();
augmenter_.clear();
return status;
}

void AR::resizeGL(int width, int height)
{
Vec2I size = Vec2I(1, 1);
if (camera_.isOpened())
size = camera_.size();
if (size[0] == 0 || size[1] == 0)
return;
if (portrait_)
std::swap(size[0], size[1]);
float scaleRatio = std::max((float)width / (float)size[0], (float)height / (float)size[1]);
Vec2I viewport_size = Vec2I((int)(size[0] * scaleRatio), (int)(size[1] * scaleRatio));
viewport_ = Vec4I(0, height - viewport_size[1], viewport_size[0],      viewport_size[1]);
    }

void AR::initGL()
{

}

void AR::render()
{

}

void AR::setPortrait(bool portrait)
{
portrait_ = portrait;
}

ARVideo::ARVideo()
{
prepared_ = false;
found_ = false;
callback_ = NULL;
}

ARVideo::~ARVideo()
{
player_.close();
if (callback_)
delete callback_;
}

void ARVideo::openVideoFile(const std::string& path, int texid)
{
if (!callback_)
callback_ = new CallBack(this);
path_ = path;
player_.setRenderTexture(texid);
player_.setVideoType(VideoPlayer::kVideoTypeNormal);
player_.open(path.c_str(), kStorageAssets, callback_);

}

void ARVideo::openTransparentVideoFile(const std::string& path, int texid)
{
if (!callback_)
callback_ = new CallBack(this);
path_ = path;
player_.setRenderTexture(texid);
player_.setVideoType(VideoPlayer::kVideoTypeTransparentSideBySide);
player_.open(path.c_str(), kStorageAssets, callback_);
}

void ARVideo::openStreamingVideo(const std::string& url, int texid)
{
if (!callback_)
callback_ = new CallBack(this);
path_ = url;
player_.setRenderTexture(texid);
player_.setVideoType(VideoPlayer::kVideoTypeNormal);
player_.open(url.c_str(), kStorageAbsolute, callback_);
}

void ARVideo::setVideoStatus(VideoPlayer::Status status)
{
LOGI("video: %s (%d)\n", path_.c_str(), status);
if (status == VideoPlayer::kVideoReady) {
prepared_ = true;
if (found_)
player_.play();
}
if (status == VideoPlayer::kVideoCompleted) {
if (found_)
player_.play();
}
}

void ARVideo::onFound()
{
found_ = true;
if (prepared_) {
player_.play();
}
}

void ARVideo::onLost()
{
found_ = false;
if (prepared_)
player_.pause();
}
int ARVideo::duration(){
if (prepared_) {
return player_.duration();
}else{
return 0;
}
}
int ARVideo::currentPosition(){
if (prepared_) {
return player_.currentPosition();
}else{
return 0;
} 
}
bool ARVideo::pause(){
if (prepared_)
player_.pause();
return false;
}

bool ARVideo::play(){
if (prepared_)
return player_.play();
return false;
}

void ARVideo::seek(int pos){
if(prepared_){
   player_.seek(pos);
}
}


void ARVideo::update()
{
player_.updateFrame();
}

ARVideo::CallBack::CallBack(ARVideo* video)
{
video_ = video;
}

void ARVideo::CallBack::operator() (VideoPlayer::Status status)
{
video_->setVideoStatus(status);
}

}
}
```

*renderer.hpp*

```
#ifndef __EASYAR_SAMPLE_UTILITY_SIMPLERENDERER_H__
#define __EASYAR_SAMPLE_UTILITY_SIMPLERENDERER_H__

#include "easyar/matrix.hpp"

namespace EasyAR{
namespace samples{

class VideoRenderer
{
public:
void init();
void render(const Matrix44F& projectionMatrix, const Matrix44F& cameraview, Vec2F size);
unsigned int texId();
private:
unsigned int program_box;
int pos_coord_box;
int pos_tex_box;
int pos_trans_box;
int pos_proj_box;
unsigned int vbo_coord_box;
unsigned int vbo_tex_box;
unsigned int vbo_faces_box;
unsigned int texture_id;
};

}
}
#endif
```

*renderer.cc*

```
#include "renderer.hpp"
#if defined __APPLE__
#include <OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h>
#else
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
#endif

const char* box_video_vert="uniform mat4 trans;\n"
        "uniform mat4 proj;\n"
        "attribute vec4 coord;\n"
        "attribute vec2 texcoord;\n"
        "varying vec2 vtexcoord;\n"
        "\n"
        "void main(void)\n"
        "{\n"
        "    vtexcoord = texcoord;\n"
        "    gl_Position = proj*trans*coord;\n"
        "}\n"
        "\n"
;

const char* box_video_frag="#ifdef GL_ES\n"
        "precision highp float;\n"
        "#endif\n"
        "varying vec2 vtexcoord;\n"
        "uniform sampler2D texture;\n"
        "\n"
        "void main(void)\n"
        "{\n"
        "    gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, vtexcoord);\n"
        "}\n"
        "\n"
;

namespace EasyAR{
namespace samples{

void VideoRenderer::init()
{
    program_box = glCreateProgram();
    GLuint vertShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertShader, 1, &box_video_vert, 0);
    glCompileShader(vertShader);
    GLuint fragShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragShader, 1, &box_video_frag, 0);
    glCompileShader(fragShader);
    glAttachShader(program_box, vertShader);
    glAttachShader(program_box, fragShader);
    glLinkProgram(program_box);
    glUseProgram(program_box);
    pos_coord_box = glGetAttribLocation(program_box, "coord");
    pos_tex_box = glGetAttribLocation(program_box, "texcoord");
    pos_trans_box = glGetUniformLocation(program_box, "trans");
    pos_proj_box = glGetUniformLocation(program_box, "proj");

    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo_coord_box);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_coord_box);
    const GLfloat cube_vertices[4][3] = {{1.0f / 2, 1.0f / 2, 0.f},{1.0f / 2, -1.0f / 2, 0.f},{-1.0f / 2, -1.0f / 2, 0.f},{-1.0f / 2, 1.0f / 2, 0.f}};
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cube_vertices), cube_vertices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo_tex_box);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_tex_box);
    const GLubyte cube_vertex_texs[4][2] = {{0, 0},{0, 1},{1, 1},{1, 0}};
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cube_vertex_texs), cube_vertex_texs, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo_faces_box);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_faces_box);
    const GLushort cube_faces[] = {3, 2, 1, 0};
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cube_faces), cube_faces, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program_box, "texture"), 0);
    glGenTextures(1, &texture_id);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
}

void VideoRenderer::render(const Matrix44F& projectionMatrix, const Matrix44F& cameraview, Vec2F size)
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_coord_box);
    const GLfloat cube_vertices[4][3] = {{size[0] / 2, size[1] / 2, 0.f},{size[0] / 2, -size[1] / 2, 0.f},{-size[0] / 2, -size[1] / 2, 0.f},{-size[0] / 2, size[1] / 2, 0.f}};
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cube_vertices), cube_vertices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glUseProgram(program_box);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_coord_box);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos_coord_box);
    glVertexAttribPointer(pos_coord_box, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_tex_box);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos_tex_box);
    glVertexAttribPointer(pos_tex_box, 2, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(pos_trans_box, 1, 0, cameraview.data);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(pos_proj_box, 1, 0, projectionMatrix.data);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_faces_box);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}

unsigned int VideoRenderer::texId()
{
    return texture_id;
}

}
}
```

I think that this is a lot of code but in order to get the solution and thank you for your help .

Comment: look at error log go to the path of output.txt file and copy paste the logs as code over here

Comment: can you find the address below "see the compile at log" output.txt file address

Comment: post the code of your  .cc files and .hpp files that might be helpful

Comment: This is the log report : [link](https://cdn.fbsbx.com/v/t59.2708-21/18740978_1526066354117976_5969742350866448384_n.txt/manifest-merger-arm-debug-report.txt?oh=cdaabed9f21fe5696a4d6205531fe87b&oe=59406250&dl=1)  . and I'm going to add more detail in my question like the .cc code and .hpp code.

Answer (score 0):

Try following things
check the path of EasyAR.jar file and in the include statement (all except `#include <string>`) in both .hpp files add the path like this `app/libs/armeabi-v7a/easyar/camera` here app is the parent directory of libs folder(if the folder name is not app)

what is happening?
your .hpp files are not getting the path of the files that it is including from EasyAR.jar , if the above method didn't work change path back to `#include easyar/...` and put the jar file (EasyAR.jar) into the jni directory.
tell me if it works or not

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work ^^, if do you want to test the project here it is the [link](https://github.com/Jerome-MJ/EasyARVideo)